# How would I export information produced from script onto a text file

Tags: bash, scripts

Scripting novice here.

I have created a script which can show you the ip address of the website which has been entered.

My script:

```
#! /bin/bash

echo "Enter web address : "
read address 
echo "Entered web address : $address"
nslookup "$address"
```

Script in use:

```
Enter web address : google.com

Server:     127.0.1.1
Address:    127.0.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 216.58.206.46
```

How would I then export that information into a text file?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
./someScript.sh > someFile.txt
```

Now enter address (e.g. google.com) and hit enter

Or more correct solution - edit script.
For example:

```
#! /bin/bash

echo "Enter web address : "
read address 
echo "Entered web address : $address"
nslookup "$address" > someLogFile.txt
```

UPD fr you:

The '>' sign here means redirection to file , so if you will type `echo 666 > file.txt` there will be created file.txt with 666 text inside.

Comment: @Jymes , you're welcome